# Python: How to read all files in a directory?

Tags: python, glob

I found this piece of code that reads all the lines of a specific file.

How can I edit it to make it read all the files (html, text, php .etc) in the directory "folder" one by one without me having to specify the path to each file? I want to search each file in the directory for a keyword.

```py
 path = '/Users/folder/index.html'
 files = glob.glob(path)
 for name in files:  
     try:
         with open(name) as f:  
             sys.stdout.write(f.read())
     except IOError as exc:
         if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:  
             raise
```

Comment: if that keyword if found what you want to do then???

Comment: @Hackaholic ill just print something for now

Comment: check the code i have given

Comment: @Hackaholic I am now getting No such file or directory: 'index.html'

Answer (score 27):

## Update Python 3.4+

### Read all files

```py
from pathlib import Path

for child in Path('.').iterdir():
    if child.is_file():
        print(f"{child.name}:\n{child.read_text()}\n")
```

### Read all files filtered by extension

```py
from pathlib import Path

for p in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
    print(f"{p.name}:\n{p.read_text()}\n")
```

### Read all files in directory tree filtered by extension

```py
from pathlib import Path

for p in Path('.').glob('**/*.txt'):
    print(f"{p.name}:\n{p.read_text()}\n")
```

Or equivalently, use `Path.rglob(pattern)`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for p in Path('.').rglob('*.txt'):
    print(f"{p.name}:\n{p.read_text()}\n")
```

### Path.open()

As an alternative to `Path.read_text()` [or `Path.read_bytes()` for binary files], there is also [`Path.open(mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open), which is like the built-in Python function [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

```py
from pathlib import Path

for p in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
    with p.open() as f:
        print(f"{p.name}:\n{f.read()}\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for updating. will be useful for others who come across this

Answer (score 23):

```
import os
your_path = 'some_path'
files = os.listdir(your_path)
keyword = 'your_keyword'
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(your_path, file)):
        f = open(os.path.join(your_path, file),'r')
        for x in f:
            if keyword in x:
                #do what you want
        f.close()
```

`os.listdir('your_path')` will list all content of a directory
`os.path.isfile` will check its file or not

Comment: The edited code has no output at all except Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It is supposed that you change the line `#do what you want" with your own code that will do what you want including printing any output.

Comment: This code isn't complete and it doesn't really work and thus doesn't serve the purpose of this question. Change the `if os.path.isfile(file):` with `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(your_path,file)):`. Then it will open the file.

Comment: In case that you are having problems with encoding reading the file, add  ```f=open(your_path_file,'r', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")```