# Reading multiple files at once in python

Tags: python, for-loop, file-read

I have written a code in python which reads through a single column of a file and gives the output as either 'P' or 'R' depending on the if/else condition I've given. I want to change it such that it stops reading the file the moment it gets the first P or R and prints that as the output. Also, I have a thousand of such files so I'm having to keep changing the file name each time I run it. Could anyone please make changes to this code so that I can run it at once and get an output for all files? All such files are in the same directory and these are the only files in the directory. Could anyone also tell me how to store or print the output for corresnponding files?

```
    f = open('/home/abc/xyz/coord/coord_348.xvg')


    dat = f.readlines()
    dat1 = dat[22:len(dat)]
    dat2=[]
    for k in dat1:
        dat2.append(k.split())
    res=[]
    for k in dat2:
        if float(k[1])>=9.5:
          print('P')
          res.append
        elif float(k[1])<=5.9:
          print('R')
          res.append
        else:
          res.append

    print(res)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: How to read all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695903/python-how-to-read-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: @Alex, this answer doesn't answer my question completely as it is not telling me how do I stop the reading of a file once I get either R or P as I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can streamline your loop initially like so:

```py
with open("file.xvg", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i < 22:
            # Skip up to line 22
            continue

        line = line.strip().split()

        # It isn't clear what you want to append to `res`
        if float(line[1]) >= 9.5:
            print("P")
            break  
        elif float(line[1]) <= 5.9:
            print("R")
            break  
        else:
            print("N")
```

This parses the file instead of reading it into a list and parsing the list. The [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement takes you out of the loop through the file.

If you have many files in a directory you can read through them like so:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path("/path/to/directory").rglob("*.xvg"):
    with file.open("r") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            # Same logic as above
            pass
```

Comment: How do I store know which file is giving what output? @Alex

Comment: That is the `file` variable. See the [pathlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: This is giving me an error:
elif float(line[1]) <= 5.9:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That is an issue with the code you are running, most likely an indentation error.

Comment: could you please suggest me a fix? I'm new to programming and not able to figure out.

Comment: Not without seeing all of the code. The SyntaxError most likely comes from the file being formatted (indented) wrong or a typo of some kind.