# Traversing directories in Python

Tags: python, directory, traversal

I am brand new to Python and have never really worked with files/directories in any sort of code before, so I apologize if I'm not explaining this right.

I am being given a folder called 'datafiles' that has 3 subfolders called run.x where x is an int. The user will input int 1, 2, or 3 to access the appropriate subfolder.

Within each subfolder are text files that read each line from.

How do I go inside of the 'datafiles' folder, then the appropriate subfolder, and then finally open the text file to read?

I've tried googling this, but everything that comes up is just a lot for me to look at as I've never even gone as far as opening a folder before. I'm just hoping someone could dumb this down for me so I can fully comprehend how to accomplish this task.

Comment: `with open(f"datafiles/run.{x}/myfile.txt", "r") as f:`?

Comment: Would f then represent the text file I have opened then?

Comment: That's the idea. You should read the docs re: `open` and reading from text files in general.

Comment: This might help you get started: [Python: How to read all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695903/python-how-to-read-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Try looking for answers to your individual problems, instead of trying to solve the whole thing in one go. How to change directories in Python? How to open a file? How to read from a file? How to open a file in a specific directory? Etc. If any of those in particular give you trouble, that could be a good StackOverflow question - your current question is too broad and getting someone here to just write the code for you wouldn't help you all that much, nor is it what SO is for.